# Skipping facebook company verification on payments for test

Tags: facebook-payment-dialog

I want to know if it's possible to make use of the [new facebook payments dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/) without having to pass the facebook company verification?

I already registered a fake company on the Apps > My app > Payments section of Facebook Developers, however now when I'm trying to add the testers for my app or the Payments callback URL facebook is complaining with this error:

"There was an error attaching the app to the company. Further bank verification needed."

Doesn't they provide a way to test the "Facebook payments dialog" without having to register a real company and passing the verification? Also, they say that the verification can take even from 2 up to 4 weeks, this looks like a lot of requirement and IMHO they should provide a way for playing with this without having to pass for all the real approbation process.

PD: I already know about the option that they offer to [test the payments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/testing/) but that's not what I'm looking for now, since this requires of the app to be approved first (actually that's the issue that I'm facing right now).